# How to remove box-shadow left when navigate screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

[image]

I need to customize the color or border-left or box-shadow left when navigate screen.

Please help me!

Comment: Could this be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: @UweKeim
Thank you so much.
This is the first time I joined and ask questions